# Websites designed to choose/upload file not working in WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview, webview2

I have a website that uploads audio but the button to choose file not responding when clicked in WebView but works in any browser. Please help me solve the issue because I have no knowledge in Java and android development. I am just trying to convert my website to android app.

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIDEO_CAPTURE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUDIO_CAPTURE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RaTVad"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is MainActivity.java

```
 package com.ratvad.ratvad;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    Context context;
    ImageView nointernet;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wbView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://ratvad.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");


        nointernet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nointernet);
        if (!isConnected()){
            nointernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No internet, please check your internet connection.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()!=null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

     @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
     }
 }
```